# how to mock useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library

I want to call a test for following code:

```
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(() => true);
  const [dataready, setdataready] = useState(() => false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(loading === false){
       setdataready(true)
    }
  }, [loading])
```

how do I render the component with this code then call setlonading(false) so useEfect gets executed again?
I want to run it in same test unit:

```
it('test my component', () => {
    .....
    render(<MyComponent />)
    .....
})
```

Comment: How does `setLoading(false)` get called in the code? Please share the rest of the code for that component.

Comment: setloading gets called in another useEffect(() => {fetchdata(); // then setlonading(false)}, []).. like that

Comment: If you could had the rest of the relevant code to the question that would be helpful. But from your description all these would happen when the component is mounted, so you just have to wait for it to do so.